# Should I spend time with my girlfriend?

Tags: persona-4-golden

Once I've got as close as I can to my girl, is there any point spending any more time with her? Or should I just spend time with other girls? Will my girlfriend miss me? I know I can always visit the hot springs with her, but are there any other reasons for us to hang out?

Comment: Not sure why there are downvotes?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf if I had to guess, it's the clickbait nature of the title

Comment: @Vemonus I suppose I can see that, although this site seems to be no stranger to questions with funky titles. Oh well, to each their own.

Comment: Your girlfriend won't miss you, but she'll be very disappointed if you don't spend time with her on Christmas or Valentine.

Comment: I genuinely wanted to know the answer to this, but I will admit that, while composing it, I found I could not resist phrasing it like a question to an agony aunt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to check to make sure Persona 4 followed the same pattern as 3 and 5, which I'm more familiar with, but it appears that it does. That is, you don't get anything for hanging out with your girlfriend (or any social link, for that matter) after they have hit max rank.

From [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/641695-persona-4-golden/66910292):

> no, you don't get anything by spending time with them after maxing SLs.

However, it's worth mentioning that maxed social links will have an additional scene at the end of the game if you talk to them on the final day.